# UnsatisfiedDependencyException in Spring : Illegal arguments for constructor : argument type mismatch

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection

**I'm trying to inject DepartmentDAO in DepartmentService. This appeared after i've added @Transactional annotations. So here is my DepartmentService:**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DepartmentService extends AbstractCRUDService<DepartmentDTO> {

    private DepartmentDAO departmentDAO;

    public DepartmentService() {
        super();
        this.departmentDAO = null;
    }

    @Inject
    public DepartmentService(DepartmentDAO departmentDAO) {
        super();
        this.departmentDAO = departmentDAO;
    }

    @Override   
    public Long create(DepartmentDTO dDTO) {        
        Department department = new Department();
        department.setDepName(dDTO.getDepName());
        return departmentDAO.create(department);
    }
...............read,update,delete,findAll methods...........................
}
```

**And here is my DepartmentDAO:**

```
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public class DepartmentDAO extends AbstractCRUDDao<Department> {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DepartmentDAO.class);
    protected Class<DepartmentDAO> clazz;

    public DepartmentDAO() {    

    }

    @Override   
    public Long create(Department d) {
    entityManager.persist(d);
    return d.getId();
    }
 ...............read,update,delete,findAll methods...........................
}
```

**Here is an applicationContext.xml:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    ">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="net.sam" />
<context:component-scan base-package="net.sam.servlets" />
<context:component-scan base-package="net.sam.dao.impl" />
<context:component-scan base-package="net.sam.services.impl" />
<context:component-scan base-package="net.sam.model.impl" />

<!-- declare EntityManagerFactory -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="net.sam.jpa" />
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass"    value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" />
</bean>

<!-- inject into JPATransactionManager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
</bean>

<!-- enable container managed transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

**My stacktrace:**

```
    мар 29, 2013 4:46:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production envi
ronments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\
bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/
bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\W
INDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Mercurial\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Se
rver\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSV
N\bin;c:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.4-bin\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;C:\Program Files\eclipse;;.
мар 29, 2013 4:46:35 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.e
clipse.jst.jee.server:chardymov-webapp' did not find a matching property.
мар 29, 2013 4:46:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
мар 29, 2013 4:46:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1710 ms
мар 29, 2013 4:46:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
мар 29, 2013 4:46:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.35
мар 29, 2013 4:46:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
мар 29, 2013 4:46:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
29-03-13 16:46:38,669  INFO [ContextLoader:initWebApplicationContext:272] - Root WebApplicationConte
xt: initialization started
29-03-13 16:46:38,741  INFO [XmlWebApplicationContext:prepareRefresh:503] - Refreshing Root WebAppli
cationContext: startup date [Fri Mar 29 16:46:38 EAT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
29-03-13 16:46:38,797  INFO [XmlBeanDefinitionReader:loadBeanDefinitions:315] - Loading XML bean def
initions from URL [file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/mach/workspace/clean2/.metadata/.plugins/org.
eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/chardymov-webapp/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml]    
29-03-13 16:46:39,270  INFO [AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor:<init>:139] - JSR-330 'javax.injec
t.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
29-03-13 16:46:39,374  INFO [LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:createNativeEntityManagerFactory
:283] - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'net.sam.jpa'
29-03-13 16:46:39,599  INFO [Version:<clinit>:37] - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.
1.Final}
29-03-13 16:46:39,599  INFO [Version:logVersion:41] - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.9.Final}
29-03-13 16:46:39,607  INFO [Environment:<clinit>:239] - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
29-03-13 16:46:39,607  INFO [Environment:buildBytecodeProvider:342] - HHH000021: Bytecode provider n
ame : javassist
29-03-13 16:46:39,647  INFO [Ejb3Configuration:configure:527] - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUni
tInfo [
    name: net.sam.jpa
    ...]
29-03-13 16:46:39,960  INFO [DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:configure:96] - HHH000402: Using Hi
bernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
29-03-13 16:46:39,960  INFO [DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:configure:130] - HHH000115: Hiberna
te connection pool size: 20
29-03-13 16:46:39,960  INFO [DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:configure:133] - HHH000006: Autocom
mit mode: true
29-03-13 16:46:39,960  INFO [DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:configure:147] - HHH000401: using d
river [org.h2.Driver] at URL [jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:db1]
29-03-13 16:46:39,960  INFO [DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:configure:152] - HHH000046: Connect
ion properties: {autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}
29-03-13 16:46:40,104  INFO [Dialect:<init>:123] - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H
2Dialect
29-03-13 16:46:40,144  INFO [TransactionFactoryInitiator:initiateService:73] - HHH000268: Transactio
n strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
29-03-13 16:46:40,152  INFO [ASTQueryTranslatorFactory:<init>:48] - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTransla
torFactory
29-03-13 16:46:40,217  INFO [Version:<clinit>:27] - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.1.Final
29-03-13 16:46:40,570  INFO [SchemaExport:execute:343] - HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: alter table EMPLOYEES drop constraint FK4351FF658ECC7308
29-03-13 16:46:40,578 ERROR [SchemaExport:perform:425] - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table EMPLOY
EES drop constraint FK4351FF658ECC7308
29-03-13 16:46:40,578 ERROR [SchemaExport:perform:426] - Table "EMPLOYEES" not found; SQL statement:
alter table EMPLOYEES drop constraint FK4351FF658ECC7308 [42102-170]
Hibernate: alter table EMPLOYEES drop constraint FK4351FF6530EEAB88
29-03-13 16:46:40,578 ERROR [SchemaExport:perform:425] - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table EMPLOY
EES drop constraint FK4351FF6530EEAB88
29-03-13 16:46:40,578 ERROR [SchemaExport:perform:426] - Table "EMPLOYEES" not found; SQL statement:
alter table EMPLOYEES drop constraint FK4351FF6530EEAB88 [42102-170]
Hibernate: drop table DEPARTMENTS if exists
Hibernate: drop table EMPLOYEES if exists
Hibernate: drop table ROLES if exists
Hibernate: create table DEPARTMENTS (id bigint generated by default as identity, depName varchar(20)
 not null unique, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table EMPLOYEES (id bigint generated by default as identity, name varchar(20) not 
null, surname varchar(255), department_fk bigint not null, role_fk bigint not null, primary key (id)
, unique (name, surname))
Hibernate: create table ROLES (id bigint generated by default as identity, roleName varchar(20) not 
null unique, primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table EMPLOYEES add constraint FK4351FF658ECC7308 foreign key (department_fk) refer
ences DEPARTMENTS
Hibernate: alter table EMPLOYEES add constraint FK4351FF6530EEAB88 foreign key (role_fk) references 
ROLES
29-03-13 16:46:40,602  INFO [SchemaExport:execute:405] - HHH000230: Schema export complete
29-03-13 16:46:40,674  INFO [DefaultListableBeanFactory:preInstantiateSingletons:577] - Pre-instanti
ating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1d98539: de
fining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.sp
ringframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.an
notation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAn
notationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,comp
osite,departmentDAO,employeeDAO,roleDAO,departmentService,employeeService,roleService,entityManagerF
actory,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframewor
k.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.inte
rceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,o
rg.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of
 factory hierarchy
29-03-13 16:46:40,730  INFO [DefaultListableBeanFactory:destroySingletons:434] - Destroying singleto
ns in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1d98539: defining beans [
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.
context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.inter
nalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProces
sor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,composite,departme
ntDAO,employeeDAO,roleDAO,departmentService,employeeService,roleService,entityManagerFactory,transac
tionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.
annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.Transa
ctionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframe
work.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hiera
rchy
29-03-13 16:46:40,738  INFO [LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:destroy:441] - Closing JPA Entit
yManagerFactory for persistence unit 'net.sam.jpa'
29-03-13 16:46:40,738  INFO [SchemaExport:execute:343] - HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: alter table EMPLOYEES drop constraint FK4351FF658ECC7308
Hibernate: alter table EMPLOYEES drop constraint FK4351FF6530EEAB88
Hibernate: drop table DEPARTMENTS if exists
Hibernate: drop table EMPLOYEES if exists
Hibernate: drop table ROLES if exists
29-03-13 16:46:40,746  INFO [SchemaExport:execute:405] - HHH000230: Schema export complete
29-03-13 16:46:40,746  INFO [DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:stop:156] - HHH000030: Cleaning up 
connection pool [jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:db1]
29-03-13 16:46:40,746 ERROR [ContextLoader:initWebApplicationContext:307] - Context initialization f
ailed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com
posite' defined in file [C:\Documents and Settings\mach\workspace\clean2\.metadata\.plugins\org.ecli
pse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\chardymov-webapp\WEB-INF\classes\net\sam\Composite.cla
ss]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [net.sam_sol
utions.services.impl.DepartmentService]: : Error creating bean with name 'departmentService' defined
 in file [C:\Documents and Settings\mach\workspace\clean2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.
core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\chardymov-webapp\WEB-INF\classes\net\sam\services\impl\DepartmentServ
ice.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstanti
ationException: Could not instantiate bean class [net.sam.services.impl.DepartmentService]
: Illegal arguments for constructor; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argumen
t type mismatch; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'departmentService' defined in file [C:\Documents and Settings\mach\workspac
e\clean2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\chardymov-webapp\WEB-INF\cla
sses\net\sam\services\impl\DepartmentService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class 
[net.sam.services.impl.DepartmentService]: Illegal arguments for constructor; nested excep
tion is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorRes
olver.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorRes
olver.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor
(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(
AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(Abstra
ctAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(Abstract
AutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.ja
va:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingl
etonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java
:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1
93)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(De
faultListableBeanFactory.java:605)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(A
bstractApplicationContext.java:925)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContex
t.java:472)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLo
ader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.j
ava:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'd
epartmentService' defined in file [C:\Documents and Settings\mach\workspace\clean2\.metadata\.plugin
s\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\chardymov-webapp\WEB-INF\classes\net\sam\ser
vices\impl\DepartmentService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springfra
mework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [net.sam.service
s.impl.DepartmentService]: Illegal arguments for constructor; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalA
rgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorRes
olver.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor
(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(
AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(Abstra
ctAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(Abstract
AutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.ja
va:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingl
etonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java
:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1
93)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(Defa
ultListableBeanFactory.java:872)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(Default
ListableBeanFactory.java:814)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultLi
stableBeanFactory.java:731)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(Construct
orResolver.java:795)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorRes
olver.java:723)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [n
et.sam.services.impl.DepartmentService]: Illegal arguments for constructor; nested excepti
on is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstanti
ationStrategy.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorRes
olver.java:280)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 40 more
мар 29, 2013 4:46:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframewor
k.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com
posite' defined in file [C:\Documents and Settings\mach\workspace\clean2\.metadata\.plugins\org.ecli
pse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\chardymov-webapp\WEB-INF\classes\net\sam\Composite.cla
ss]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [net.sam_sol
utions.services.impl.DepartmentService]: : Error creating bean with name 'departmentService' defined
 in file [C:\Documents and Settings\mach\workspace\clean2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.
core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\chardymov-webapp\WEB-INF\classes\net\sam\services\impl\DepartmentServ
ice.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstanti
ationException: Could not instantiate bean class [net.sam.services.impl.DepartmentService]
: Illegal arguments for constructor; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argumen
t type mismatch; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'departmentService' defined in file [C:\Documents and Settings\mach\workspac
e\clean2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\chardymov-webapp\WEB-INF\cla
sses\net\sam\services\impl\DepartmentService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class 
[net.sam.services.impl.DepartmentService]: Illegal arguments for constructor; nested excep
tion is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorRes
olver.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorRes
olver.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor
(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(
AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(Abstra
ctAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(Abstract
AutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.ja
va:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingl
etonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java
:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1
93)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(De
faultListableBeanFactory.java:605)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(A
bstractApplicationContext.java:925)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContex
t.java:472)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLo
ader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.j
ava:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'd
epartmentService' defined in file [C:\Documents and Settings\mach\workspace\clean2\.metadata\.plugin
s\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\chardymov-webapp\WEB-INF\classes\net\sam\ser
vices\impl\DepartmentService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springfra
mework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [net.sam.service
s.impl.DepartmentService]: Illegal arguments for constructor; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalA
rgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorRes
olver.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor
(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(
AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(Abstra
ctAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(Abstract
AutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.ja
va:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingl
etonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java
:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1
93)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(Defa
ultListableBeanFactory.java:872)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(Default
ListableBeanFactory.java:814)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultLi
stableBeanFactory.java:731)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(Construct
orResolver.java:795)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorRes
olver.java:723)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [n
et.sam.services.impl.DepartmentService]: Illegal arguments for constructor; nested excepti
on is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstanti
ationStrategy.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorRes
olver.java:280)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 40 more

мар 29, 2013 4:46:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
мар 29, 2013 4:46:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/chardymov-webapp] startup failed due to previous errors
мар 29, 2013 4:46:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
мар 29, 2013 4:46:40 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/chardymov-webapp] registered the JDBC driver [org.h2.Driver] but faile
d to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver h
as been forcibly unregistered.
мар 29, 2013 4:46:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
мар 29, 2013 4:46:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 9757 ms
```

Comment: You're going to want to post the whole stack trace, please.

Comment: ... and please tell us the bean which fails to be created, and maybe show us the rest of your spring beans configuration.

Comment: You won't need Transactional on your Dao, imo

Comment: Thanks for yours attention,guys. I've added stacktrace. DepartmentService fails to be created. And i haven't got any other beans congiguration files except applicationContext.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Transactional` is implemented as a proxy, IMHO Spring does not resolve proxy type as `DepartmentDAO`. In this case you have 2 solutions:

- make your DA implement an interface and inject it via this last
- Enable CGLib proxy in Spring configuration

Comment: Thanks a lot, i've changed fields and constructor argument types to Interfaces like IDepartmentDAO.And now it works.It's seems that Spring couldn't create proxy objects using Abstract classes

Comment: It can but using cglib proxies

Comment: @Gab why it is a problem for the Spring to recognize a cglib proxy as a valid bean?